# Dell EC not detected after Windows crashed accessing it but is detected again when accessing it after some time. EC failure or compatibility issue?

Tags: windows, laptop-repair, chipset, dell-studio, sensors

When accessing Dell Embedded Controller (EC), which should be a temperature sensor on Dell Studio XPS 1645 notebook PC with SpeedFan and HWInfo, Windows would randomly crash with BSOD with memory-related error. After crashing, the EC wouldn't be able to be accessed anymore on subsequent startups of the programs until some time later that it is being detected again when opening the programs. And the cycle continues.

HWInfo does prompt warning about the possible instability while accessing the EC. However, the fact that the EC is able to be accessed again some time later making it looks like hardware issue.

So, do you think this would be the EC hardware failure, or the inherent compatibility issue between the EC hardware and the software applications?

Comment: Sounds like a driver problem

Comment: Drivers are verified to be properly installed.